# Find the depth of a pond using a rope

Tags: geometry

My name is Shaun and I am 13 years old. I am stuck with a problem, which roughly translates to this:

“A straight rope is anchored in the middle of a squarish pond with sides of 4. The rope, when perpendicular to the pond, rises above the surface of the pond by 1.5 meters.

If one drags the rope across one of the ponds corners, it touches the surface. How deep is the pond?”

Does anyone know how to even begin with this?

(I am sorry if my English translation may not be well understood. I translated this from the original swedish text of a problem of Chinese origin.)

My attempt:

[image]

What I understood after discussing a little bit:

[image]

Solving for d, I get approximately 1.9 meters, which also works with the answer sheet. However I just do not understand one thing fully: how does the new height become d + 1.5?

---

Now, here is my steps to solve for this. If there is anything wrong with it, please give me some feedback:

1. Let d be the depth of the squarish pond with sides of four.
2. Denote the perpendicular rope, anchored from the middle, in the form of variable d: 1.5 + d. This becomes our hypotenuse when touching one of the top corners of the cube.
3. The base of the triangle can be found by taking half the diagonal of the base of the cube: sqrt(32)/ 2
4. Using The Pythagorean Theorem, we can solve for d, which approximately equals to 1.9 meters (exact = 23/12).

---

Thank you to everyone who helped me with this problem. I am very grateful for your help. Thank you!

Comment: Use Pythagoras' theorem to build an equation for depth $h$ of the pond.

Comment: Hi! I am really sorry but I can not see where the right angled triangle is to be able to use Pythagoras Theorem

Comment: Join the center of pond bottom with bottom corner.

Comment: Next time, use a ruler for displaying a nicer-looking graphical representation : it takes just a few seconds more... or use Geogebra (instruction "Cube")

Comment: I just guessed for the new height

Comment: Okay Jean Marie! Thank you for the feedback

Comment: $d$ in your drawing is a leg of the right triangle. The string is the hypothenuse. The length of the string is $d+1.5$

Comment: Thank you Vasili!

Comment: You wrote: “we can solve for d, which approximately equals to 1.9 meters.” Using Pythagoras' theorem you must have found the _exact_ value, don't you? (It should be 23/12.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right triangle mentioned in comments has the hypothenuse equal to the length of the string, the vertical leg equal to length minus 1.5 and the horizontal leg equal to half of diagonal of the pond.

$$ l^2=(l-1.5)^2+x^2, x=2\sqrt{2}$$

$$l=\frac{8+2.25}{3}=\frac{10.25}{3}$$

The depth of the pool is $l-1.5=1\frac{11}{12}$

$\therefore$ The depth of the pool is exactly $1\frac{11}{12}$m.